# function in $\mathbb R^n$ defined by $x^2 - y^2 -z^2 = 9$

Tags: calculus

Can someone help me with this exercise from calculus?

sketch in $\mathbb{R}^n$ the solid defined by $x^2 - y^2 -z^2 = 9$

Thanks

Comment: @amd asked: How does this help the O.P. sketch the graph on her own? in response to my plot of the surface $x^2-y^2-z^2=9$. So I have deleted the plopt. But what does the question mean? Why $\mathbb{R}^n$? Why "solid"? What is the difficulty?

Comment: The dificulty is that i didn't know ho to sketch the solid but know i already understand how to do

Answer (score 0):

Set up a graph with three axis: x , y and z. (I assume you know how).
You'll have to complete the three-dimensional graph with two-dimensional curves.
This means that you need to complete it with the curve in the xy plane (when z=0), in the xz plane (y=0) and the yz plane (z=0). 
If you need additional guidance you could plot graphs with two axis (x,y) (x,z) (y,z) and then use them as guidance to complete the three dimensional graph.
If you want to know how that surface looks, you could search for any 3D plotter / grapher online. I don't think I need to upload it here.
Cheers.